# Every time I edit SCSS, Parcel crashes the hot reloading with a Build Error

Tags: javascript, sass, bundler, web-development-server, parceljs

I've just started using Parcel and I love it compared to webpack. The simplicity is incredible for someone like myself who doesn't necessarily need a tool like webpack yet.

That being said, I am running into a problem with using it during development. Every time I make changes in my editor to an SCSS file, while I have a dev server running, the server crashes with a "Build Error" basically saying that "@parcel/transformer-sass: expected" correct code, but since I was literally in the process of writing it while it was compiling it, it read the SCSS in it's incomplete form and failed.

How do I prevent this? This doesn't happen while I'm editing javascript with a dev server running. I know the answer is probably incredibly obvious, but I've been unable to find it by googling around for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was helped by changing the VSCode autosave settings from "after
delay" to "on focus change"

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31992666)

Comment: this helped me as well, a bit of a hack